# If $f(x)=\frac{-8(1-\sqrt{1-x})^3}{x^2}$, then $f(f(x))=x$. Slick proof?

Tags: radicals, alternative-proof, elementary-functions

In the paper [A tribute to Dennis Stanton](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0196885810001016?via%3Dihub) Richard Askey gives the following problem

If $f(x)=\frac{-8(1-\sqrt{1-x})^3}{x^2}$, then find $f(f(x))$.

I managed to solve it, but spend several hours and used a lot of paper in the process. My proof is not elegant, I just verified it by direct substition. I wonder is there any simple and elegant proof?

Askey writes:

> It is a nice problem with a surprising answer, which I leave to the
> reader. Hint, the first surprise might not be the only one.

So the first surprise is probably the fact that the answer is $x$, which I established.

> **Question**: What is the other surprise that Askey mentions?

Comment: If you can show that $y=f(x)$ is symmetrical with respect to $y=x$, then you could conclude that $f$ is it's own inverse, i.e. $f(f(x))=x$

Comment: Actually $f$ can be decomposed into composition of several functions and their inverses. This makes the proof much easier. I might elaborate on this once I got the time.

Comment: [Check out the graph on Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/k9yiv3zobb). $f(f(x))=x$ at least for $x\in[-8,1]$. Maybe the surprise is what happens at $x=-8$?

Comment: The equation $y=-8\dfrac{(1-\sqrt{1-x})^3}{x^2}$ can be transformed to $x^2y^2-48xy+64(x+y)=0$, which is symmetric in $x,y$. Hence $f$ is its own inverse.

Comment: For x=-15 we get 8*3^3/15^2!=15

Comment: @IAmAGuest  i have posted a CW answer with graphs that illustrate your point.

Answer (score 7):

If we get rid of the square root in $y=\frac{-8(1-\sqrt{1-x})^3}{x^2}$ by setting $u=(1+\sqrt{1-x})/2$ (those $1+$ and $/2$ are not really needed, but they give nicer formulas), we get
$$x=-4(u^2-u),\qquad y=-4(u^{-2}-u^{-1}).$$
So to pass from $x$ to $y$ we replace $u$ by $u^{-1}$, and if we do it again, we get back $u$, and thus the original $x$.

Possibly this is the "official" proof, as the paper that you linked says that Stanton came up with this problem while working with quadratic transformations, and $u\mapsto -4(u^2-u)$ is a quadratic transformation.

And if I'm not supposed to be sloppy: I guess that all the numbers should be real and so $x\leq 1$, and $\sqrt{1-x}\geq0$. For any $x\leq 1$ we have *two* solutions $u$ of $x=-4(u^2-u)$, namely $(1\pm\sqrt{1-x})/2$; we want the $+$-sign (that's how I defined $u$), i.e. the solution with $u\geq 1/2$. Now if we replace $u$ by $u^{-1}$, we'll keep the inequality $u\geq1/2$ only for $u\in[1/2,2]$. So it's only in this interval that we get $f(f(x))=x$; the interval is $u\in[1/2,2]$, i.e. $x\in[-8,1]$, fitting the graph from @Graviton's comment above.

Comment: Nice way to prove it.

Comment: wow.............

Comment: there was a comment after your answer, the graph, if we chop it off at $x \le 1,  y \leq 1,  x \geq -8, y \geq -8$   is symmetric across $y=x,$  by reflection

Comment: @WillJagy I included now the reason why things change for $x<-8$

Answer (score 1):

Here I am illustrating the comment of @IAmAGuest   as to the graph of the given function is a portion of the graph of a symmetric (implicit)  relation $x^2 y^2 -48 x y +64(x+y) = 0.$  Note that the $x$ partial derivative is zero at $x=-8, y=1,$  while the $y$ partial vanishes at
$x=-8, y=1 \; . \;$

I tried to get the scale the same in the two graphs. I also told it to draw a diagonal line segment to indicate exactly what parts match up

[image]

[image]